# Bush wanderer console game

Tags: game, powershell

I had read the question: [Bush Wanderer - code intended for teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121196/bush-wanderer-code-intended-for-teaching) and wanted to play with PowerShell. Including the rules of the game from that same question.

> **Bush Wanderer**
>
> Task 1
>
> Create a 5x5 grid of hashes(`#`) where the player is an `x` on the
>   board
>
> Prompt the player to move in either N, E, S or W direction and then
>   reprint the board to show the new position.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> x # # # #
> # # # # # 
> # # # # #
> # # # # #
> # # # # #
> Which way would you like to move?(N,E,S or W)
> ```
>
> Task 2
>
> - Ensure the player does not move off of the board
> - Place a hidden chest somewhere on the board at random
> - End the game when the chest is found
> - Tell the player how many moves it took to find the chest
> - Add a visible (but blind) dragon that can teleport around the board    at random and will eat you and end your game if it gets you before
>     you get the chest

---

Made with PowerShell v4.0. I tried to use an enum but had to create a type using c# which I don't do much. I take advantage of how PowerShell does variable scoping a far bit in this code. From [about_scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847849.aspx)

> An item you include in a scope is visible in the scope in which it           was created and in any **child scope**

Instead of passing more parameters into my functions I just call them in the parent scope of the script which occurs by default. I also changed the player character to P as that made more sense to me.

I use the PromptForChoice to get the users choice. I had wanted to use that logic and remove the choices that are not available to the user but I can't control the choice index that is returned so I present all choices and will continue to prompt until the user enters a valid direction choice.

If someone reviews this and questions my function names that is all well and good but just know I am trying to adhere to the [approved verb list for PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx). You are welcome to comment on this either way though. Don't hold back!

```
# Coordinate template to use to represent object locations in the board jagged array.
[char]$bushSymbol = "#"
$entityTemplate = @{X=0;Y=0;Character=$bushSymbol}
$moves = 0

# Determine the size of the board.
$boardSize = 5

# Base direction choices enum
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   public enum Direction
   {
      North = 0,
      South = 1,
      East = 2,
      West = 3
   }
"@

# Game board flags.
$gameOver = $false

# Initialize Game board entities from template
$playerCharacter = $entityTemplate.psobject.Copy()
$playerCharacter.Character = "P"
$dragonCharacter = $entityTemplate.psobject.Copy()
$dragonCharacter.Character = "D"
$treasureChest = $entityTemplate.psobject.Copy()

# Initialize Game board object as a jagged array
$gameBoard = 1..$boardSize | ForEach-Object{,(@($bushSymbol) * $boardSize)}

# Menu text. 
$title = "Which way?"
$message = "Which direction would you like to travel?"

function Get-PlayerDirectionChoice(){
    # This function will present the end user with viable direction choices. Choices can be limited based on current location.
    $options = ([Direction]::GetNames([Direction]) | ForEach-Object{
        New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&$_", "Character will attempt to travel $($_.ToLower())"    
    })

    return $host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 
}

function Get-RandomBoardPosition([hashtable]$Entity, [int]$BoardSize){
    # Get a random x and y. Number are between 0 and the boardsize minus 1
    $entity.X = Get-Random -Maximum $boardSize
    $entity.Y = Get-Random -Maximum $boardSize
}

function Test-ValidPlayerDirection([Direction]$choice){
    # Function will return a boolean based on the propsed movement of the player character on the board.
    $result = $true        # Assume true

    # Check to see if the player is on any of the boundries
    if($playerCharacter.Y -eq 0 -and $choice -eq [Direction]::North){$result = $false}
    if($playerCharacter.Y -eq ($boardSize - 1) -and $choice -eq [Direction]::South){$result = $false}
    if($playerCharacter.X -eq ($boardSize - 1) -and $choice -eq [Direction]::East){$result = $false}
    if($playerCharacter.X -eq 0 -and $choice -eq [Direction]::West){$result = $false}

    return $result
}

function Test-EntityCollision($FirstEntity, $SecondEntity){
    # Test to see if two entities have the same X and Y values. If they do return true.
    if($FirstEntity.X -eq $SecondEntity.X -and $FirstEntity.Y -eq $SecondEntity.Y){
        return $true
    } else {
        return $false
    }
}

function Show-GameBoard{
    # Function will display on console the current game board layout as populated with it entities. 
    Clear-Host 

    # Edit in the positions of the objects.
    $gameBoard[$playerCharacter.Y][$playerCharacter.X] = $playerCharacter.Character
    $gameBoard[$dragonCharacter.Y][$dragonCharacter.X] = $dragonCharacter.Character

    # Function will draw the game board to the console. 
    0..($boardSize - 1) | ForEach-Object{$gameBoard[$_] -join " "}
}

# Get the starting location of all board entities
$treasureChest, $dragonCharacter, $playerCharacter | ForEach-Object{
    Get-RandomBoardPosition -Entity $_ -BoardSize $boardSize
}

# Start the game. Show the board
Show-GameBoard

Do{
    # Get the gardener to put the bushes back before the character leaves.
    $gameBoard[$playerCharacter.Y][$playerCharacter.X] = $bushSymbol

    # Determine where the player is going to go. 
    $choice = Get-PlayerDirectionChoice
    if(Test-ValidPlayerDirection ([Direction]::GetName([Direction],$choice))){
        # Move the character based on the choice selected. 
        switch($choice){
            ([Direction]::North -as [int]) {$playerCharacter.Y = $playerCharacter.Y - 1}
            ([Direction]::South -as [int]) {$playerCharacter.Y = $playerCharacter.Y + 1}
            ([Direction]::East -as [int])  {$playerCharacter.X = $playerCharacter.X + 1}
            ([Direction]::West -as [int])  {$playerCharacter.X = $playerCharacter.X - 1}
        }
        # Raise the moves
        $moves++

        # Show the updated board
        Show-GameBoard

        # Check to see if the dragon caught the player
        if(Test-EntityCollision $playerCharacter $dragonCharacter){"The Dragon eats you and you took $moves move(s)."; $gameOver = $true}

        # Check to see if the player found the treasure
        if(Test-EntityCollision $playerCharacter $treasureChest){"You found the treasure in $moves move(s)."; $gameOver = $true}

        # Get the gardener to put the bushes back before the dragon leaves.
        $gameBoard[$dragonCharacter.Y][$dragonCharacter.X] = $bushSymbol

        # Move the dragon 
        Get-RandomBoardPosition -Entity $dragonCharacter -BoardSize $boardSize

    } else {
        # The choice used would place the player out of bounds.
        Write-Host "You are blocked by a magical force and cannot move that way."
    }
} While(-not $gameOver)
```

What the start of the game looks like

```
# # # # #
# # # # #
# D # # P
# # # # #
# # # # #

Which direction would you like to travel?
You are looking for a chest that is hidden in the bushes. Watch out for the clumsy Dragon that will eat you if he
catches you.
[N] North  [S] South  [E] East  [W] West  [?] Help (default is "N"):
```

A sample success screen

```
# # # # P
# # # # #
# D # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #
You found the treasure in 14 move(s).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like it, I learnt a few things about objects from this. I also really liked the board size can be easily changed.

### Immediate Collision

When playing I noticed the Dragon was allowed to start in the same position as the Player. While it's not explicitly stipulated in the tasks, it might be nice to avoid that:

```
$treasureChest, $dragonCharacter | ForEach-Object {
    Get-RandomBoardPosition -Entity $_ -BoardSize $boardSize
}
Do {
   Get-RandomBoardPosition -Entity $playerCharacter -BoardSize $boardSize
} Until ($playerCharacter.Y -ne $dragonCharacter.Y -or $playerCharacter.X -ne $dragonCharacter.X)
```

---

### The C# Type

Replace the C# type with:

```
$Directions = @{
   North = 0
   South = 1
   East = 2
   West = 3
}
```

Replace all instances of `[Direction]::North` and `[Direction]::North -as [Int]` with `$Directions.North`.

Change parameter type of `Test-ValidPlayerDirection` from `[Direction]` to `[String]` (or omit the type altogether).

New `Get-PlayerDirectionChoice` function:

```
function Get-PlayerDirectionChoice(){
    $options = $Directions.GetEnumerator() | % {
       New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription $_.Name
    }

    $host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 
}
```

And testing the direction:

```
$choice = Get-PlayerDirectionChoice
if(Test-ValidPlayerDirection ($choice)){
...
```

---

### Function full of `If`s

Instead of evaluating conditions, setting return values then returning a `[Bool]`, return the condition itself:

```
function Test-ValidPlayerDirection($choice){
   Return -not (
      ($playerCharacter.Y -eq 0 -and $choice -eq $Directions.North) -or
      ($playerCharacter.Y -eq ($boardSize - 1) -and $choice -eq $Directions.South) -or
      ($playerCharacter.X -eq ($boardSize - 1) -and $choice -eq $Directions.East) -or
      ($playerCharacter.X -eq 0 -and $choice -eq $Directions.West)
   )
}

function Test-EntityCollision($FirstEntity, $SecondEntity){
    Return $FirstEntity.X -eq $SecondEntity.X -and $FirstEntity.Y -eq $SecondEntity.Y
}
```

---

The loop was working fine, but it seemed odd the Dragon would move before the next turn and after a collision had been checked. You could reorder the loop from this:

```
# Get the gardener to put the bushes back before the character leaves.
# Determine where the player is going to go. 
# Move the character based on the choice selected. 
# Raise the moves
# Show the updated board
# Check to see if the dragon caught the player
# Check to see if the player found the treasure
# Get the gardener to put the bushes back before the dragon leaves.
# Move the dragon
```

To this:

```
# Determine where the player is going to go. 
# Get the gardener to put the bushes back before the character leaves.
# Move the character based on the choice selected. 
# Get the gardener to put the bushes back before the dragon leaves.
# Move the dragon 
# Raise the moves
# Show the updated board
# Check to see if the dragon caught the player
# Check to see if the player found the treasure
```